# How are questions for reopen audits chosen? Can we exclude some?

Tags: support, review-audits

Are questions for audits chosen randomly or by hand? I'm talking about reopen queue specifically.

I'm asking because of [this audit](https://superuser.com/review/reopen/270475). "Works for me" comments indicate that the [question](https://superuser.com/q/792048/194694) could actually be closed until more details are provided by OP, but I've failed the audit by leaving it closed. It has in fact drawn my attention, so it kind of worked, but I don't think my decision should be recognized as failure.

Comment: well, it was [never closed](https://superuser.com/posts/792048/revisions)

Comment: Because somebody figured out that it's a buffering issue, but the problem was hard to reproduce just with provided info. The audit stated that it was closed and I thought close reason is not right ("too broad"), but it could stay closed because of missing info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comments on this were indeed a red herring, if it weren't for them you'd probably be wondering how or why the question was ever closed in the first place, and voted to reopen it.

The selection isn't random, the system tries very hard to give you an *extremely* obvious selection of what it thinks are extremely good questions that almost *everyone* would take the same action with. That doesn't work 100% of the time, the system has no idea what people were saying in comments, and every other indicator it had said "that's a great candidate for a review".

Audits will always state that what *should* look like a fantastic question was closed, leaving anyone actually paying attention screaming What the *heck*?! *Why?!*. It's rare that context the system can't comprehend makes this sort of muddy, but it does happen once in a while.

Don't worry about the occasional failed audit where the selection was poor, or that you simply find yourself at odds with actions that the community took. As long as you're paying close attention, there's nothing else to worry about.